# How to change the Field Help of standard field in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I would like to modify the Field Help of NetSuite's Standard / Native field. How to do?

Thanks for reading this question.

Any type of related information will definitely help me to move a step ahead towards solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried without success UserEvent Script on BeforeLoad event this (SS2.0):

```
scriptContext.form.getField('tranid').setHelpText({help:'Test'});
```

The example above is working only with fields created by scriptContext.form.addField.
 
There is no way to do it with ClientScript (no access to setHelpText method there).
And of course, there is no customization tool.

 The only way is to use DOM, which is not recomended by Netsuite, and for sure is not a good practice.

Comment: Thanks for spending time on this. Seems like this is there in the list of NetSuite enhancements ( #66689).

Comment: Good to hear. At least it is in the list.